# Avoiding reevaluation of ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been using ng-options to build a selector for values that will change very sporadically. In my non-toy example, I have around 50 or so options in the array and I noticed a slowdown every time I would make a change. I discovered that it was reevaluating ng-options every single time I made a change to my selection. Is there a way to avoid this? I have a toy example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BBra9/2/

Essentially, this function:

```
scope.formatItem = function (item) {
    console.log('formatting item.');
    return item.someProp1 + '/' + item.someProp2;
};
```

is being called to format each item for display in the selector, but I only want to have it run once per item on the initial static list.

The console in Chrome shows a total of 9 logging statements made before I ever make a selection and a subsequent 3 per change afterwards. My initial guess is to use `compile` but I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run it at the beginning and cach the values as a separate property

```
for (var i=0;i< scope.someList.length ;i++){
   scope.someList[i].someProp3 = scope.formatItem(scope.someList[i]);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BBra9/3/)